# How to decode an encoded POST data

Tags: c#, decode

From a payment provider I get the data as a `POST` and encoded with

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
```

the issue is that I need to retrieve the data from the

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

and a simple `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.Form[0])`

returns:

```
"\" transactionRef\"\r\n\r\nd68cafc5d6c8472a893eb0763efca625\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKVsW8jF9QdwY35ca\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"transactionNumber\"\r\n\r\n10526728\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKVsW8jF9QdwY35ca\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"orderRef\"\r\n\r\nc7853c2513fd45758b80b95a2dbaf9fa\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKVsW8jF9QdwY35ca\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"orderId\"\r\n\r\n50043628\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKVsW8jF9QdwY35ca\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"accountNumber\"\r\n\r\n50250954\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryKVsW8jF9QdwY35ca\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"zzzz\"\r\n\r\nmust be here to get http post to work"
```

How can I decode the data so I can retrieve each parameter correctly? for example, extract the `transactionRef` or `orderRef`?

I did it in a very weird way and I just wonder if there's something easier/failproof that we can use:

[image]